# Why can't I debug twig templates with intellij idea?

Tags: theming, debugging

I can't get intellij idea to break on twig files. It is breaking on theme and module files fine. This means that xdebug must be setup correctly. I don't believe that it is caching as I've deleted the cache files

```
drush ev '\Drupal\Core\PhpStorage\PhpStorageFactory::get("twig")->deleteAll();'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the twig cache path was not set for the project.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/05/twig-and-blade-templates-debugging-2/